# How were the first 169 blocks mined if no transactions occured before block 170?

Tags: genesis-block

My guess is that there is that you are able to leave the transaction parameter empty, but I have not been able to find confirmation.

Comment: Indeed, there is no requirement that a block contain any transactions besides the coinbase. The ultimate reference is the source code.